# Is there any problem with Generics in Java 11?

Tags: java, generics, java-11

I have this generic class for API

```
abstract class EntityRestAPI<A, T, K extends Serializable, E> {
       protected T fromEntity(E entity) {
            entity
       }
       ....
}
```

and extend it like this

```
class Customers extends EntityRestAPI<CustomerSummary, CustomerInfo, Integer, Customer> {
      @Override
      protected CustomerInfo fromEntity(Customer entity) {
            ...
      }
}
```

This compiles in Java8, but has follow error in Java11

```
The return type of service.Customers.CustomerInfo fromEntity(Customer) in service.Customers is incompatible with CustomerInfo fromEntity(Customer) in service.EntityRestAPI
```

Comment: not able to reproduce, could you complete the implementation and try compiling with `javac` as well? Minimal code I had tried - `abstract class EntityRestAPI<A, T, K extends Serializable, E> {
        protected T fromEntity(E entity) { return null; }
    }

    class Customer { }

    class CustomerSummary { }

    class CustomerInfo { }
    
    class Customers extends EntityRestAPI<CustomerSummary, CustomerInfo, Integer, Customer> {
        @Override
        protected CustomerInfo fromEntity(Customer entity) { return null; }
    }`

Comment: Do you have two classes named `CustomerInfo`?

Comment: @Holger No, just once.

Comment: @Naman Your right, it means that my problem irrelevant to Java version. Thanks